# Fork: Negative return value

Tags: c, fork

From the fork(2) man page:

```
RETURN VALUE
   On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and
   0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the  parent,
   no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.
```

I am wondering about the reasons that would make a fork call fail. What are the case scenarios where fork returns -1?

I am writing a standard Unix shell in C. How should I handle the error?

Comment: I can't make out what you mean by your last question. Are you talking about shell scripts or the shell itself or where are you going with this?

Comment: You're right. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the C API, system calls return a negative value to indicate an error, and the error code in `errno` gives more information on the nature of the error. Your man page should explain the possible errors on your system. There are two [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) error codes:

- `EAGAIN` indicates that the new process cannot be created due to a lack of available resources, either insufficient memory of some kind or a limit that has been reached such as the maximum number of processes per user or overall.
- `ENOMEM` indicates that the new process cannot be created due to a lack of memory of some kind. Under Linux, `ENOMEM` indicates a lack of kernel memory, while a lack of userland memory is reported as `EAGAIN`. Under OpenBSD, `ENOMEM` is used for a lack of userland memory as well.

In summary, `fork` can fail due to a lack of available resources (possibly in the form of an artificial limit rather than a simple lack of memory).

The behavior of shells when `fork` fails is not specified by POSIX. In practice, they tend to return different error statuses (1 in pdksh, 2 in ash, 254 in bash, 258 in ksh93, 1 in tcsh; zsh returns 0 which is a bug). If you're implementing a shell for production use (as opposed to a learning exercise), it might be worth discussing this on the [Austin Group](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/) mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

I know that the kernel has a parameter `NPROC` which tells it the maximum amount of processes which can be run at the same time. I imagine if you're already at the maximum and try creating another one, you will be denied from the kernel and return -1 to your parent.

On another note, the kernel also has a limit of processes per user stored in the `MAXUPRC` parameter. Same deal applies as above.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason would be the inability to spawn a new process due to quota limitations or some system failure.

When writing software you may not always know why something might fail, but having a clearly defined way to handle every step if it doesn't go right is always a good idea.